# I have an error while running android app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK

Comment: When you enable USB debugging, a dialog will show up asking you to confirm that. Then, after you plug your device into your PC, another dialog will show up also asking to confirm your action. In both cases, you have to choose allow access option. Otherwise, it will be marked as `device unauthorized`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open Settings
- Goto developer options
- Click revoke USB debugging authorizations

and then click to run the app and accept the dialog box in the phone